# NSIS - msiexec /i fails with code 1619 if I call SetOutPath

Tags: windows-installer, nsis

`ExecWait "msiexec /i myinstaller.msi /qn" $0`

That's all I'm calling in my script. (The `/qn` is for silent installation without popping up any progress window, I've also tested without it).

It fails with an [msiexec error code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229683) of 1619-`This installation package could not be 
                                opened. Verify that the package exists and 
                                that you can access it, or contact the 
                                application vendor to verify that this is 
                                a valid Windows Installer package.`

The same msiexec call works fine on the commandline, or if I write a basic NSIS script that does nothing else- which means it's **not** because of [NTFS permissions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316309) that a Google search throws up.

Therefore, it must be something else in my main installer script.
After commenting out nearly everything in my script to isolate the cause:

`SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\Some directory"`

If I comment this section out and don't set an output path, everything works fine. What on earth is going on? Why should this interfere with the msiexec call?

**Update** - Here's the `tl;dr` version of the problem - the following snippet doesn't work when run as an independent script unless I comment out the `SetOutPath` call. WHY?
It does not matter whether the output directory has any files in it or not(it doesn't), or whether I call it immediately before or several lines before.

```
showinstdetails show
 OutFile test.exe
section
 setoutpath "D:\back"
 ExecWait "msiexec /i MyInstaller.msi /qr" $0
 MessageBox MB_OK $0
sectionend
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what was wrong, with partial help from Nick and Anders above.
In my other script which worked, I was calling `SetOutPath` **after** invoking the MSI.

Changing the sequence worked.

So lesson learned - relative paths get screwed up after calling `SetOutPath` , so in my original example, the path to the msi would be resolved against what was set in `'SetOutPath` instead of using the current directory, where the installer is located.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

There could be two things wrong here.  The msi should really be in quotes, and you should really be giving the full path to that msi.  The first is important if you include a path with spaces in; the second is important as msiexec.exe needs to know where that msi is - it may well not be in the system path.

Something like this should work (if the installer is in the %TEMP% folder):

```
ExecWait 'msiexec /i "$TEMP\myinstaller.msi" /qn'
```

Comment: The msiexec is in the same directory as the overall installer package. Also, it only fails if I use SetOutPath.

Comment: What's the path BEFORE you set your out path (i.e. where's your msi file ending up if you have SetOutPath commented out)?  ExecWait runs from C:\Windows\System32\, so unless your outpath is in the system path, ExecWait won't be able to find it unless you've included the path in the msiexec call.

Comment: Got it..have posted an answer and included your comments :)

Answer (score 1):

SetOutPath sets the current/working directory for the process. (So using it will affect any relative paths later in the script)

You should always use full paths when possible and with correct quotes:

`ExecWait 'msiexec /i "$exedir\myinstaller.msi" /qn' $0` (Replace $exedir with the correct path if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$PLUGINSDIR` directory and place `myinstaller.msi` there. It is temp folder which will be deleted automatically after installer exited.

```
InitPluginsDir 
File /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\myinstaller.msi "myinstaller.msi"
```

Then full path to `myinstaller.msi` should be used in the `ExecWait`.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I only face a problem if I call SetOutPath. Otherwise it is able to launch the MSI just fine.

Comment: Maybe an opened handle? Have you tried it with different output path set just before ExecWait?

Comment: Done that. Updated question to reflect this.